# How to call specific get method from ASP.NET ApiController using Angularjs controller?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I have ApiController class that includes multiple GET methods.

```
    //method 1   
    public IEnumerable<Drive> GetProducts()
    {
                  ...
    }

    //method2
    public IEnumerable<string> GetCustomer(string name)
    {
                  ...
    }

    //method3
    public IEnumerable<string> GetCustomers()
    {
                  ...
    }
```

This is my angularjs script

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:53551/api/values/GetProducts').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.strings = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("sa");
        });
    debugger;
    $scope.open = function (name) {
        debugger;
        $http.get('http://localhost:53551/api/values/GetCustomer?' + name ).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.strings = data;
            })
    };
    });
```

All functions only call GetProducts(). But I want to call each time a specific one.
Is it possible to call specific GET method through angularjs from ApiControler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had DefaultWebAPI route registered as below

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

then you just need to call method name `/api/controllerName/actionName`(don't need to mention `HttpVerb` in action name). The prefix before each action name indicates the nature of Action. I assumed you have `ValuesController` that has all above mentioned actions.

```
http://localhost:53551/api/values/customer
http://localhost:53551/api/values/products
http://localhost:53551/api/values/customers
```